# Subtract result precision issue

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288904/division-returns-zero)

Say you have the code below.

```
double d=16/60; //I got d is 0.0 , but I expected d could be 0.27.
```

How to make it ?thanks.

**Edit for the Best Answer :)**

```
double d=16/60f;
d= Math.Round(d, 2); //result being 0.27
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242436/c-divide-an-int-by-100 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400799/division-in-c-sharp-not-going-the-way-i-expect

Comment: How is that the "Best Answer"? The resulting value of `d` is `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

At least one of the operands needs to be a floating point type (`float` or `double`).

```
double d=16/60f;

double d=16f/60;

double d=16/60d;

double d=16d/60;

double d=16.0/60;

double d=16/60.0;
```

Comment: Note: The suffix of `f` specifies a `float` literal value that could lead to more prominent rounding errors, especially when implicitly casting it to double later. Either the suffix `d` should be sued to denote a `double` literal value, or a decimal floating point should be used (like in the last two example in the answer), which in C# creates a `double`. For example, `double d = 0.123f;` would produce a value of `0.123000003397465`. Unless you have specific performance or memory requirements, it's best to avoid `float` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Make a cast

```
double d = (double)16 / (double)60
```

Or:

```
double d = Convert.ToDecimal(16)/Convert.ToDecimal(60)
```

Comment: instead of casting or converting just use literals of the right type in the first place.